# How to calculate the number of Logical Processor?

Tags: cpu, virtualization, processor

What I know is

```
Number of Logical Processor = Core x Sockets x HT
```

Is it right ? How many Virtual Machines are possible to provision with this logical processor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly , so if it has `2 Procs` with `4 Cores` and `HT` enabled then the

```
Number of logical processor  = 2 x 4 x 2 = 16
```

> ESX will also use a core, so if you take the simplistic view of
>   allocating cores to VMs, you only have 7 to "allocate".

Have a look at this [VMware community question](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/183436) on ESXi CPU.